# Can I parse long arguments with Elixir's built-in OptionParser?

Tags: arguments, elixir

I am using Elixir's `OptionParser`, but I am having problems parsing long dashed arguments.

Preferably, I would like to do something like this:

```ruby
OptionParser.parse(argv, strict: ["db-username": :string, "db-password": :string])
```

But this does not seem to work. I'm getting `Unknown option`.

Anybody knows if it is possible somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OptionParser has this (slightly weird) behaviour, where it corrects your option names from using underscores to using dashes and doesn't let you specify the arguments with dashes yourself.

```
iex(1)> argv = ["--db-username", "foo"]
["--db-username", "foo"]
iex(2)> OptionParser.parse(argv, strict: ["db-username": :string, "db-password": :string])
{[], ["foo"], [{"--db-username", nil}]}
iex(3)> OptionParser.parse(argv, strict: ["db_username": :string, "db_password": :string])
{[db_username: "foo"], [], []}
```

This makes it a bit more natural when you provide the arguments spec as atoms instead of strings, you can just do `:db_username`, instead of `:"db-username"`.

This behaviour [is documented](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/OptionParser.html#parse/2), but it's easy to miss.